# Is it possible to simplify such multivarible inequality

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

Ive got this inequality
$$
    a^{2}>-b^{2} 
$$

To simplify, Ive tried expanding into

$$
(a+ib)(a-ib)>0
$$

$$
a>-ib \ \& \ a>ib
$$
Which looks absurb to me, since its impossible to compare the value between a real and imagindary number.
So is it not possible or is there another way out?

Comment: As $a$ and $b$ are real, $a^2 \ge 0$, and $-b^2 \le 0$. The set on which your inequality is satisfied is consequently $\mathbb{R}^2 - \{(0,0)\}$.

Comment: But what if b is a complex number, how does it apply? Sorry if my question sounds stupid

Comment: The complex numbers aren't ordered, so so an inequality between two of them is a little absurd without further qualification. Roughly, I mean that there's no canonical way to compare $1 + 2i$ and $2 - i$, and you need to tell me what $>$ means for you before I can comment on the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $a^2>-b^2$ is equivalent to $a^2+b^2>0$. The second inequality is true for all real numebrs $a,b$ except for $a=b=0$. If we assume that numbers $a,b$ can be complex numbers, then we get that an inequality $a^2>-b^2$ is true for all complex numbers except for $a^2+b^2=0$, so $(a-ib)(a+ib)=0$. Thus, an inequality $a^2>-b^2 $ is held for all complex numbers $a,b$ except for $a=bi$ or $a=-bi$.